# Facebook Lead Ads API - Field identifiers in multiple languages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having a problem with some generated forms and their integration with my CRM. Some forms come with fields in Portuguese (nome_completo, numero_telefone, etc) and other forms come in English (full_name, phone_number, etc).

Is there any way to unify this so it always comes in just one language? Regardless of how the form was registered?

I'm using the PHP SDK to do the integration

I've already tried to register several forms in different languages ​​to see if the fields came in different languages ​​and they were coming, but I don't know how to unify this in a single language, regardless of the language of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my reading of the [documentation](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/144047185946009?id=735435806665862), we need to change the language of the instant forms manually.
So, if you are [fetching forms fields](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/leadgen_forms), then you can not control the language of the form yet because they have clear mentions that there are no parameters for their forms fetching endpoint.[image]

Similarly, the control of the response for leads retrieval as per this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/), and as per my best understanding is not provided yet. They will just give the response in what language they will get.

So, you can not get form fields in one language as there is no customization provided yet. You can also talk to their support as well for more clarification. Sometimes, the features are provided but not mentioned in the document and they can guide you as well.